# como defino campo timestamp symfony 3 y easyadminbundle

Tags: mysql, symfony3, doctrine2

Como puedo hacer que una entidad almacene un campo createdAt y updatedAt con doctrine2 mapeado por anotacion? ... Mi entidad es User.
Estoy usando easyadminbundle para administrar el backend.

Comment: y por qué no usas para esto triggers mejor?

Comment: Disculpa soy bastante nuevo en el framework y no conozco como funcionan los triggers.

Comment: Los triggers no tienen que ver con symfony, mas bien los haces en la base de datos. Son disparadores que se activan cuando ocurre un evento a una tabla, por ejemplo una inserción o modificación. Puedes hacer uno para cuando ocurra el evento de 'insertar usuario' y otro para el de 'actualizar usuario'

Comment: Ah bien. Entiendo ahora como funcionan. Busco y si me da la solución escribo nuevamente. Gracias Adriana Hernández.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te han comentado, puedes usar trigger, pero esto genera dependencia de la base de datos, y en la mayoría de los proyectos en los que se usa un ORM es algo no deseable.

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer con los `lifecyclecallbacks` de `doctrine`. Es muy sencillo.

Suponiendo que tienes la entidad mapeada con `Annotations`, sería así:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface {

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updateAt;

    // ...

}
```

Y dentro de esta clase creamos un método que será llamado en los eventos que nosotros configuremos, para este caso, valdrá con los eventos `PrePersist` y `PreUpdate`

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onSaveAction()
{
    if (!$this->getCreationDate()) {
        $this->createAt = new DateTime();
    }

    $this->updateAt = new DateTime();

    // Resto de la lógica antes de guardar, puede ser por ejemplo, comprobar un campo

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() para doctrine funcionó a la perfección. No quiere decir que los otros métodos estén mal. Pero para mi caso específico fue la mejor solución.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que usas `mysql` para la base de datos, para el caso del campo `createdAt`, si quieres que se te actualice con la fecha actual al insertar un usuario puedes usar un trigger así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_user BEFORE INSERT ON User
BEGIN
IF NEW.createdAt=null THEN
INSERT INTO User SET NEW.createdAt = CURDATE();
END IF;
END
```

Pero para el caso del campo `updatedAt` no necesitas hacer un trigger ya que lo puedes poner por defecto al crear el campo, usando `Navicat`, de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O sea, seleccionando en tu caso el campo `updatedAt` y luego seleccionas la opción de abajo `On Update Current_Timestamp`